# How to keep the double quotes in double quotes using sed

Tags: linux, powershell, shell, sed

For example,

```
echo "hello, mon saids "I am tired", Sorry"
```

The result is :

```
hello, mon saids I am tired, Sorry
```

The expected result:

```
hello, mon saids "I am tired", Sorry
```

I know we can use

```
echo "hello, mon saids \"I am tired\", Sorry"
```

But I suppose to do this in one file or many files, cannot manually insert \ to every ". Could you provide a way to do this using sed?

Comment: Use single quotes.

Comment: I would not recommend trying to automate this. A regular expression that correctly identifies nested quotes to escape will be tricky, if not impossible, to write correctly.

Comment: Can you post a sample file? Do you mean the file is a bash script including the `echo` command? Or the file only has a bunch of strings?

Comment: BTW, checking the tags on the question, are you using `powershell` (which is windows), or a `linux` shell?

Comment: The file has bunch of string, no echo in it. When we insert the file to our database, we use " " as delimiter, if a string contains ", it will be identified as a delimiter,  we want to avoid this. For example, "hello, mon saids "I am tired", Sorry" should be in one column, but now, it only has hello, mon saids in one column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes around the string as following:

```
echo 'hello, mon saids "I am tired", Sorry'
```

This way, the inner double quotes will be preserved without the need to escape them with backslashes.

Comment: Hi Megadöden, thank for your reply, I cannot put it in single quote, This is just one line in my file, I have multiple lines (more than 1 million),so I cannot manually do this.

Comment: How did you create a million broken lines in the first place? Fix the thing that generated them and recreate the files rather than trying to patch them after the fact.

Comment: Those lines were not created by me, it was created by the source team.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that using single quotes as suggested may work, so using this sed  may help

```
sed -E "s/(^.)|(.$)/'/g"
```

This can help to shift the first and the last double quotes to single ones.